# How can I create a generic method that is constrained by iterable types?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently trying to create a generic method that takes in any object that implements Iterable but I keep getting stuck. I think there's something wrong with how I wrote out my parameter. This is what I have so far. I think the only part I need to fix is the parameter.

```
public class Main 
  {
    public static <T extends Iterable> String getToString(Iterable<T> objects)
        {
             String total = "";
             objects.toString(); 
             for(T s: objects){
             total += s + "*";
        }
        return total;
 }
```

The issue is that when I call it,

```
    String words = "Hello there how are you";
    Iterable<String> it = Arrays.asList(words.split(" "));
    System.out.println(problem2_getElements(it));
```

I get the error that

```
The method getToString(Iterable<T>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<String>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` shouldn't be `Iterable`. `T` should be the element type of the collection you are iterating over:

```
public static <T> String getToString(Iterable<T> objects)
{
    String total = "";
    objects.toString(); 
    for(T s: objects){
         total += s + "*";
    }
    return total;
}
```